# Could Elon Musk sell $US6 billion in stock “right now”?

Tags: finance, elon-musk

Recently (26 October 2021), CNN published [an article](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/10/26/economy/musk-world-hunger-wfp-intl/index.html) with the eye-catching headline:

> **2% of Elon Musk's wealth could solve world hunger**, says director of UN food scarcity organization

This was subsequently [debunked on Twitter](https://twitter.com/DrEliDavid/status/1454475769200185349) to which [Elon Musk replied](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1454808104256737289):

> If WFP can describe on this Twitter thread exactly how $6B will solve world hunger, **I will sell Tesla stock right now and do it**.

Drama ensued (and is still ensuing).  David Beasley, who was CNN's source, [tweeted](https://twitter.com/WFPChief/status/1454883966071230472) *Headline not accurate. $6B will not solve world hunger*.  CNN later modified the misleading title of their original article to the vacuously true "2% of Elon Musk's wealth could *help* solve world hunger".  (See e.g. [Can we end poverty for $US175 billion per year?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10301/25398) to get an idea of how unrealistic CNN's original title is.)  TL;DR: $US6 billion is being requested to prevent 42 million people dying from starvation.

Putting aside the debunked claim that $US6 billion could “solve world hunger”, ...

**Question**: Could Elon Musk sell $US6 billion in stock “right now”?

It seems fairly clear that Elon Musk believes he could actually do this if he chose to, and has [requested specifics](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1454921466500222977) in response to David Beasley's clarification.

However (in my mind at least), selling $US6 billion in stock sounds extraordinary complicated; I would think it’d take months or even years to do so, if it were even possible at all.

Comment: Deleted political opinions about whether $6b could solve world hunger.  Comments are for improving the question.

Comment: I think the problem here is that "right now" is a very imprecise term.  It could be the second Musk recieves a reply (obviously impossible), or it could be as long as millenia: e.g. "The Earth is in an interglacial period right now" :-)

Comment: Interesting discussion [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131105/discussion-on-question-by-rebecca-j-stones-could-elon-musk-sell-us6-billion-in). Please continue it there.

Comment: We now have another [World Hunger cost](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56056/could-world-hunger-be-ended-for-40-billion-usd-per-year) question.

Comment: @jamesqf, it is imprecise, but I'd interpret this in this context as "within 30 days." A timeframe that allows basic logistics, but doesn't require big market changes, corportate restructuring, etc.

Answer (score 150):

The current [trading volume](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/) of Tesla stock is at an average of 20M shares per day. At the current stock price, that's a volume of around $24B per day. However trading volumes fluctuate and today a total of 56M shares were moved around or $67B. So the market naturally sees fluctuations that are far bigger than Elon's proposed sale of stock. Elon would also be extremely likely to sell the stock via a [block trade](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/blocktrade.asp) to minimize influence on the stock price.

That being said, company insiders have to [report their stock sales](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1062613/000106261315000049/ex995insidertradingpolicy.htm) in advance and [wait for the next window period](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1164964/000101968715004168/globalfuture_8k-ex9904.htm). For Tesla this would be around [January 2022](https://ir.tesla.com/#tab-quarterly-disclosure) given their schedule of quarterly earnings disclosures. As a company insider he is also prohibited by the same SEC rules from margin borrowing against his Tesla stocks, so he couldn’t use his stocks as collateral.

So could he sell the stock "right now"? **No**, according to SEC rules he would have to wait for the next Tesla trading window.

Could he obtain $6B "right now" to send to WFP? **Most likely yes**, by using whatever other liquid investments/cash he has or borrowing the money. He won’t be allowed to use Tesla stock as collateral but someone with his reputation could certainly secure a loan for 2% of his current net worth.

Could he quickly sell $6B on the stock market assuming it was cleared by the SEC? **Yes**, that's an amount within the usual trading volumes seen for Tesla shares.

Comment: A block trade essentially spreads out the sale over time... or involves finding (beforehand) an investor willing to buy the whole thig.

Comment: @Fizz is there a general formula on how long a block trade would take given current stock price/volume?

Comment: Given that 's it's an "umbrella term" for various practices, probably no. There's more concrete data on that at https://finance.yahoo.com/news/block-trade-002326076.html

Comment: And a $19B block trade "blew up" (in March), in the sense that it was discovered as such, sending the stocks  involved down (by $33bn). https://www.ft.com/content/1b9119b2-0d8b-4a9d-b0a2-d10a021cd71b $6B might pass though.

Comment: And then we have to assume that Musk actually holds such a volume in public stock that can actually be traded. If he's like other company owners I know and have known, a good part of their stock is excluded from public trade explicitly by the company statutes, and can only be sold either to other board members or family members (depending on the management structure of the company).

Comment: @jwenting But we're only talking about 2% of his wealth. If half of that it Tesla stock, it's only 4% of his stock, and maybe that's within the portion that he can trade publically.

Comment: @jwenting he received 11 billion in stock options [this year](https://www.reuters.com/business/autos-transportation/teslas-elon-musk-qualifies-11-billion-options-payout-2021-04-26/) as compensation for good performance. Even if his original share is illiquid, I can’t find any mentions of these options being illiquid as well.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't see any purpose in giving illiquid stock as a performance bonus. Might as well give the person real estate on the moon then.

Comment: @NeilMeyer Restricted stock units are a common form of executive compensation. They normally become marketable either at a fixed date in the future, or a specified amount of time after the employee leaves the company. The purpose of RSUs is to give the recipient an incentive to focus on long-term rather than short-term company performance.

Comment: @Nobody in any case arguing over whether or not *Elon Musk* can procur 6 billion is ridiculous at the end of the day :-)

Comment: @JonathanReez No argument there!

Comment: @JonathanReez I've in the past been offered stock options that were illiquid for the term of my employment with the company. It's pretty common.

Comment: @JonathanReez yup, we're talking about the specific 6B in stock rather than 6B in whatever funds.

Comment: @fredsbend done - added citation for both disclosures/trading windows and a link to one of the many brokerages offering loans with stock used as collateral (aka margin borrowing). You can borrow money for whatever purpose you want, its not a regular bank loan where you have to specify what you're going to use the money for. I can do it right now for my own brokerage account, up to the value of stocks in my account.

Comment: He absolutely could effectively liquidate $6bn in Tesla stock in order to donate it. While company insiders typically are not allowed to sell stock during blackout periods, there is no such restriction on donating stock. He could set up a charitable vehicle, donate $6bn of Tesla stock to that vehicle, which could then liquidate the stock.

Comment: @ASimmons I'm seeing [conflicting information](https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=2232230e-63a7-46fd-a152-87a77c144fb1) on this online. Care to add an answer of your own to clarify this?